# How to change or set the Crontrigger OwnerId?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Is there any way to change or set the crontrigger ownerId? I started an Apex Job in a Post Install Script and the ownerId is the installed package. I need change it or abort the job and start it again with the System Administratior id.

Thanks, Airton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to set the OwnerId is to be logged in as that user.

Per the [CronTrigger Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) only query is supported and you cannot use DML for this object.

The simplest way to do this is to first log in as the right user and just delete the job from setup (setup->monitor->scheduled jobs), and then reschedule (setup->develop->apex classes, click 'Schedule Apex').

You could do this with apex as well if you have the scheduled job id

```
Id jobId = '00000000000000';
String jobName = 'JobName';
String cronString = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022';
system.abortJob(jobId);
system.schedule(jobName, cronString, new SchedulableClass());
```

Comment: Hi Ralph, thank you. Is there a way to set the OwnerId when I sechedule the job?

Comment: The only way to set the OwnerId is to be logged in as that user.

Answer (score -1):

What did you try?

Here's how to set/use the scheduler ...
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: I tried to update the Owner ID, but it's not possible.

Comment: you need to delete the record and and reschedule it as you.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it in a Script, cause the schedule is created through the Post Install Script and I need to set the user as the administrator user.